# Integration measure for Polyakov's path integral

Tags: string-theory, path-integral, quantization

In section 3.4 of Blumenhagen's *Basic Concepts in String Theory*, where path integral quatization is presented, and we are given the partition function for the Polyakov's path integral
$$Z=\int \mathscr{D} h \mathscr{D} X e^{i S_P[h, X]}\tag{3.63}$$

(I think normally this would be Wick rotated to Euclidian spacetime, which effectively replace the $i$ with a minus sign.)

The integration measure is defined as

$$\begin{aligned} & \|\delta h\|^2=\int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-h} h^{\alpha \beta} h^{\gamma \delta} \delta h_{\alpha \gamma} \delta h_{\beta \delta}, \\ & \|\delta X\|^2=\int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-h} \delta X^\mu \delta X_\mu\end{aligned}\tag{3.64}$$
the same as in Polyakov's original paper. But the author states this integration measure is derivable from the following Gaussian integral
$$1=\int \mathscr{D}(\delta X) e^{-\frac{1}{4 \pi \alpha^{\prime}}\|\delta X\|^2}\tag{3.65}$$
and other variables are defined "likewise".

I am not sure how $(3.64)$ follows from this Gaussian integral definision and I did not find this in Polyakov's paper. Although it is apparent if we make the replacement $||\delta X||^2\rightarrow h^{\alpha\beta} \partial X^\mu_\alpha X^\nu_\beta \eta_{\mu\nu}$ we would recover the Polyakov action on the exponent. Also, how would one define the measure for the metric implicitly through a Gaussian integral similar to $(3.65)$?

Comment: I sent an email to Prof. Blumehagen for an inquiry about this question, it appears this idea of implicit definition of integration measure comes from Polchinski's 1985 paper *Evaluation of the One Loop String Path Integral*, but no justification or derivation is presented there, too.